# Disable output buffering on my local XAMPP server

Tags: php, output-buffering

For some reason my XAMPP server is buffering the output of my PHP. I want it to spit it out as it goes. Anyone any ideas which settings I need to change to achieve this?

Comment: Did you force flush() in your code to see the output being sent to your screen?

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script

Answer (score 3):

XAMPP appears to set `output_buffering` to 4096 by default. (So content is served in 4K chunks - a possible performance benefit. Although this can lead to unexpected bugs (eg. "headers already sent" etc.) if deploying on a server where this is disabled, which incidentally is the PHP default.)

In `php.ini`:

```
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering=4096
```

Set to:

```
output_buffering=Off
```

And restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`ob_end_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php), the manual's chapter on [output control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) - specifically the [php.ini settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).

Of course if you're just getting a blank page, check your error reporting settings - it's very possible an error halts the script, and with error reporting off you see nothing.

Comment: I checked in the php.ini output buffering is off and ob_end_flush does not give an output... could anything else be stopping my script from echoing during execution?

Comment: If you're using some kind of framework, it maybe setting up output buffering regardless of the settings. If all you get is a blank page, check error reporting. Any example code/output?

Answer (score 0):

if you are debugging this in Xdebug and checking the output in the browser there might several reason for that.
1) php
2) apache (web server)
3) Web browser

Read this for the detailed information:

http://muzso.hu/2008/02/19/php-output-buffering