# Do I have Output Buffering disabled on my server

Tags: php, buffering

I have tried various methods from posts on this site to check if output buffering is turned on and working.

Here is my source code

```
  <?php 
    ob_start();
    if(ini_get('output_buffering')) { echo 'it is on'; } else { echo 'dosent seem to be  working';}
  ?>
```

Results in "dosent seem to be working"

I have tried phpinfo function to check my server details

output_buffering    no value    no value

Am I just checking incorrectly or is it most likely that output buffering is disabled? And if its disabled why would it be? Do It companies have a good reason to disable OB.

Thanks

Comment: you can check on the php.ini if its disabled or not. Why would you need to check it from a php file?

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425806/disable-output-buffering-on-my-local-xampp-server

Comment: just use `echo ini_get('output_buffering')`. you can also use function `ini_set` tu set value of property or just change it in `php.ini`. I can't get what you exactly want, what's your point?

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini file, I have tried ini set and it produces the same results. I just need to turn output buffering ON